# pass dynamic json to ddslick js plugin

Tags: javascript, jsp

someone knows a way to pass a dynamically generated json to a js plugin

i'm making a dynamic dropdown list using the DDslick js plugin

http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

the item in the DDslick are hardcoded in json format like this

```
    var ddData = [
     {
    text: "Facebook",
    value: 1,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Facebook",
    imageSrc: "xxxxx"
    },
    {
    text: "Twitter",
    value: 2,
    selected: false,
    description: "Description with Twitter",
    imageSrc: "xxxxx"
     }      
    ];
```

this dropdown list must be dynamic, so for now i'm making a dummy json with these values

```
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("text", "xxxxx");
                json.put("value", "xxxx");
                json.put("description", "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
                json.put("imageSrc", "xxxxx");
                json2.put("text", "aaaa");
                json2.put("value", "aaaa");
                json2.put("description", "aaaa-aaaa-aaaa");
                json2.put("imageSrc", "aaaa");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             string output = json.toString()+","+json2.toString();
```

and giving the output to the plugin like this on the jsp, but none of this works, the dropdownlist is not visible

```
             var ddData = eval("${output}");
             var ddData = "${output}";
             var ddData = ["${output}"];
```

and if i hardcode the same string output in the jsp, it works

```
var ddData = [
    {"text":"xxx","imageSrc":"xxxx","description":"xxxx-xxxx-xxx","value":"xx"},
    {"text":"aaaa","imageSrc":"aaaa","description":"aaaa-aaaa-aaaa","value":"aaaa"}
];
```

Comment: Where is this dynamic JSON coming from?

Comment: its from the response of a webservice, i must make the json according to whatever the webservice brings me, but it still being developed, so i dont know in what format it will be

Comment: figure it out, the json must be passed to the js variable without the double quotes                                                                                                                                     var ddData =[${output}];

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    var ddData = JSON.parse( output );
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp